# A summation problem

Tags: summation, summation-method

Here is the question: 
My professor made this equations in a proof, however I did not understand how he gets these steps, and which technic he uses 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \int_1^k\frac {1}{x}dx=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \int_{j}^{j+1} \frac {1}{x}dx = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=j+1}^{n} \int_{j}^{j+1}\frac {1}{x}dx $$

Comment: The first equality is straightforward. The second, one use $\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k a_{jk}=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^n a_{jk}$ for $a_{jk}\geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the first expression
$$\color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^n \int_1^k \frac{1}{x}dx}$$
is the original problem. To get to the second expression, your professor uses the property of integrals
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx+\int_b^c f(x)dx=\int_a^c f(x)dx$$
To split the integral
$$\int_1^k \frac{1}{x}dx$$
into the sum of integrals
$$\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x}dx+\int_2^3 \frac{1}{x}dx+...+\int_{k-1}^k \frac{1}{x}dx$$
which he then expresses using summation notation as
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \int_j^{j+1} \frac{1}{x}dx$$
thus transforming the original expression into
$$\color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \int_j^{j+1} \frac{1}{x}dx}$$
The next transformation is fairly straightforward... your professor is merely utilizing the commutativity of addition to rearrange the sums into a more useful format.

Comment: I understood the first part, however still didnt get the second one. Can you please explain this one too?

Comment: @LeylaAlkan Try expanding the sum and rearranging it manually, or you could try proving the identity observed by ntt in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The first equation holds because
$$
\int_1^k\frac {1}{x}dx = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \int_{j}^{j+1} \frac {1}{x}dx
$$
Since in general, $\int_a^b + \int_b^c = \int_a^c$ (this is lazy notation but hopefully you know what I mean).

The second is a reordering of the summation.  Note that both sides can be written as
$$
\sum_{(j,k) \in S}\int_{j}^{j+1} \frac {1}{x}dx
$$
Where $S = \{(j,k): j,k \in \{1,2,\dots,n\} \text{ and }j<k\}$